# Something like jMonkey in C++

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics

**I like jMonkey very much because there is integrated everything** what you need for game development  into one package, with reasonable documentation support and many examples. You can just download it, and start making your game in a few minutes (based on modified examples). And it is **opensource**

**what I don't like about jMonkey is Java.** It is very limiting if you want to do a **lot of fast vector/quaternion/matrix math**. In C++ you can make overloaded operators for this math. In Java you loose quite a lot of performance by accessing objects elements and allocation of new objects (you often cannot avoid that). It is quite inconvenient to use getters and setters to protected object properties all the time, instead of just accessing numbers directly.

So I wonder if there is something with so much functinality like jMonkey ( **physical engine, scene graph, shaders, import of various 3D mesh / texture formats, networking** .... ) but being in C++ where you can write:

```
Vector1 += scalar1*Vector2*Vector3;
```

instead of

```
Vector1.add(  vector2.mul( Vector3 ).mul( scalar1 ) );
```

and not worry about construction new objects

**I made some tests:**

- in C++ with -02 optimization I got fmul (fused multiply add) of double3 in 1 processor
  tick
- in java it took ~4-6 ticks if I used just local operations of
  Vectro3f ( without allocation )
- and ~10 ticks when new object was created. Creation of new objects cannot be avoided sometimes due to architecture of Vectro3f class, and even worse with quaternions where components x,y,z,w are protected variables )

Comment: Sounds like Ogre (with OgreODE) or SDL could fit the description.

Comment: C++ code with overloaded operators might still construct temporaries, I think what you want are expression templates (e.g. like used in Eigen). This is somewhat disconnected from being a game enine though.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Simple Fast Media Library (SFML)](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), it even has a tag here: [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml)